# Adding the values of instance variables in java

Tags: java

EDIT: Temporarily lost my brain. Apologies.

If I have n Box objects in a list with an instance variable called numThings (numbers of things in each box). The numThings in each box is random. How can I count all the numThings in each box and add them together?

```
public class Box {
     int numThings = RandomHelper.nextIntFromTo(0, 10);

     class Box (int numThings) {
          this.numThings = numThings;
     }

     //set and get numThings code here

     List<Box> fullBoxes = new ArrayList<Box> ();
     if (this.numThings > 0) {
          fullBoxes.add(this);
     }
     //Not sure where to go with this. I want to know the total number of things in all the boxes combined
     public void countNumThings() {
          for (Box box: fullBoxes){
             box.getNumThings()
          }
     }   


}
```

Comment: Create a variable called sum, then add `getNumThings()` to it in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation can be:

```
public int countNumThings() {
        int totalThings=0;
        for (Box box: fullBoxes){
                totalThings = totalThings+box.getNumThings();
        }
        return totalThings;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
public int countNumFromBoxes(List<Box> fullBoxes){

int totalThings = 0;

for(Box box : fullBoxes){
    totalThings += box.getNumThings();
}

return totalThings;
}
```

Anyway, your code doesn't compile, for example, where does this belongs?

```
 if (this.numThings > 0) {
      fullBoxes.add(this);
 }
```

Please, comment and I'll edit the answer to help you.

**EDIT:** may be you are trying to have something like this, consider that in your main program you have a `List<Box>`, you may have this class:

```
public class Box {
private int numThings;

//let it have a random number of things
public Box(){
    this.numThings = RandomHelper.nextIntFromTo(0, 10);
}

//make it have certain number of things
public Box(int numThings) {
    this.numThings = numThings;

}

public static int countNumFromBoxes(List<Box> fullBoxes){

    int totalThings = 0;

    for(Box box : fullBoxes){
        totalThings += box.getNumThings();
    }

    return totalThings;
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```